# Google Docs "add a comment" shortcut (⌘+⌥+M) not working

Tags: macos, web, keyboard-shortcuts, google-docs

I cannot add a comment using Google Docs' defined shortcut on my MacBook Pro (Sierra 10.12.4, but I've been having this issue since Mavericks).

[image: Google Docs Comment Shortcut]

(Side note: The keystroke for entering a footnote works perfectly fine).

I've gone through my keyboard shortcut settings and assigned away all shortcuts that use the "M" key, here:

[image: Keyboard Shortcuts Screen]

(I've checked "Accessibility" and the other categories to ensure no use of the "M" key in any shortcuts -- active or inactive.)

Am I potentially misunderstanding in that the "option" key as defined by Google is something other than the Mac ⌥ key?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about shortcut keys in Google docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, then discovered the depressing the keys in sequence worked:

1. option
2. command
3. m

Comment: Fantastic sleuthing! This didn't work for me, but I played with the keys and my comp seems to like:
1) ⌘
2) m
3) option

(Alternatively the reverse of the above works as well, but prints the µ character, replacing the highlighted text I'm trying to comment on.)

Comment: Today I found out that Fn + Alt  + Cmd + M is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The shortcut calls for Alt. So you have to press down Fn on the Mac.

So Fn+Option+Cmd+M works.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I got was by going through the Insert menu:

1. Ctrl + Option + i
2. m

None of the other suggestions worked on my iMac Pro.